# Multiplied results when search for an a href

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have the following website source:

```
<article>
  <div class="product">
         <a class="product-desc-link" href="test.com">Find out more</a>
  </div>
<article>

<article>
  <div class="product">
         <a class="product-desc-link" href="test2.com">Find out more</a>
  </div>
<article>
```

For each article I need to print the href value. I tried with the code below.

```
sections = soup.find_all('article')
for each in sections:
    for i in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'product'}):
        link = i.find('a',href=True)
        print(link['href'])
```

The results are:

```
test.com
test2.com
test.com
test2.com
```

Why I see duplicates results? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is problem with your tags (they should be `<article>...</article>`). But the reason you are getting duplicate values is because you are finding all `div` tags with `class='product'` while iterating through articles. If you want to solve it with your code, you should do:

```
sections = soup.find_all('article')
for each in sections:
    # it shouldn't be soup.find_all(..)
    for i in each.find_all('div',{'class':'product'}):
        link = i.find('a',href=True)
        print(link['href'])
```

---

But I don't really see a reason for that second loop, so replacing it with would be even better:

```
for each in sections:
    print(each.find('a')['href'])
```

By the way, you shouldn't be using `.find_all()` if there is only one `a` tag inside `<div class="product">`.